# A query that will see which results are the most

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table where strings are stored by type.
How to write 1 query so that it counts and outputs the number of results of each type.

Tried to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id), COUNT(t2.id) 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 
ON t2.type='n1' 
WHERE t1.type='b2';
```

But nothing works.
There can be many types, how can this be done?

Comment: The `ON` condition should be a relationship between the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT t1.type, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id), COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.type = t2.type
GROUP BY t1.type
```

Note that this won't show any types that are only in `table2`. For that you'd need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which MySQL doesn't have. See [How can I do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1) for how to emulate it.